# remove spaces, but keep tabs

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have a tab-delimited text file with 3 columns.

In some of the columns there are single or multiple spaces that I want to remove. But I want to keep the tab separation between each column and also the newline character.

I tried

```
perl -lape 's/\s+//sg
```

but that removes all whitespaces, also the tab spaces

My file looks like this

```
col1 col2    col3
1    test    test
2       test test
3     test    test
```

And I want

```
col1   col2   col3
1      test   test
2      test   test
3      test   test
```

So I only want to keep the tabspaces between the different columns, but not the single spaces. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Just literal spaces? Or do you mean other non-space-whitespace?

Comment: Also - why are you doing `lape` as your flags? `pe` would seem to be sufficient here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove spaces, not `\s` which also matches tabs:

```
sed 's/ \+//g' file
```

And if you want to remove these spaces just if they occur after a tab, say:

```
sed 's/\t */\t/g' file
```

---

From [perldoc perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-character-classes):

> **\s** matches a whitespace character, the set [\ \t\r\n\f] and others

Comment: I think I'd go with `+` over `*` here. Intuitively it seems matching zero spaces and replacing it with zero spaces is redundant.

Comment: @Sobrique good point. I tried with `s/ +//g'` and didn't work, now I see I was missing to escape the `+`. Anyway, it is best to just say `s/ //g` as you suggest.

Comment: I think escaping + is required if not using `g`lobal. For example, here's how I trim spaces (excluding tabs) from each start and end of lines: `sed 's/^ \+//; s/ \+$//'`

Comment: @NoamManos the escaping of  `+` is due to using normal Sed. You can omit it if you use extended regexp: `sed -r 's/ +//g'`.

Answer (score 4):

If it's just spaces, you can use `' '` instead of `\s`.

E.g.

```
s/ //g;
```

Of course, given you're doing `lape` and `-a` means 'autosplit on whitespace' you could just:

```
perl -ane 'print join ("\t", @F );'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create you own character class that is the *negation* of all things that are *not* spaces and a tab, this character class represents all characters that are whitespace - tabs:

```
perl -lape 's/[^\S\t]+//sg'
```

`[ ... ]` defines a character class

`^` inside of `[ ... ]` negates this character class

`\S` represents everything not in `\s`

`\t` represents a tab character

Answer (score 1):

With awk, to reformat the output to use specifically a tab character,

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1}1' file
```

The odd-looking `$1=$1` forces awk to rewrite the current record using the Output Field Separator (tab)